# What is the correct way to pass arguments to the JavascriptExecutor?

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use the `JavascriptExecutor` for my code, which involved passing in a `WebElement` and get some info from it. I was getting some errors, so I simplified it down to find the problem.

`String test = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0];", "macon").toString();`

That code won't run. It'll throw a `NullPointerException`. I can avoid it by not trying to access the passed variable. It doesn't seem to matter what I pass; could be an int, string, `WebElement`, etc etc.

So what's wrong? I can't see any discrepancies between online examples and my code, but there's obviously something. I'm using the Firefox WebDriver, and my Selenium version is 2.44.0

Comment: "macon" is a string i guess and u r passing it to javascript to perform what?

Comment: It's just a test string.  I'm trying to return whatever argument is passed in and assign it in String test. It's that access of a passed in argument that isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast the results to `String`:

```
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;
String test = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0];", "macon");
```

Also, there were compatibility issues between selenium 2.44 and Firefox 35/36 which affected javascript code execution:

- [Firefox 35: Passing arguments to executeScript isn't working](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390)

Comment: Yep, going up to version 2.45 fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;

String example=(String)js.executeScript('return $('table tbodt tr td:eq(0)')') .text();
```